# Passing data from sqlite3 to html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sql, sqlite, electron

I'm trying to build an Electron Database app using sqlite3. I've successfully created a database file and a table with some data. I also created a javascript file which can add items to the table and getting itmes and print it in the command promt using console.log(). However, I want to display this data into an HTMl file which I can display when the app is started (with Electron). I also want to add more features for controlling the database file using the app I created.

I've spend a lot of time searching for a proper tutorial or example about using sqlite3 and a Electron app. However I didn't find such tutorial or example. Is there anyone who knows a tutoriol or can explain how to use sqlite3 and Electron proper?

Comment: If you can add to your question your code that creates your initial window and the code used to get the result set from your `sqlite3` database that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You've noted that you are using SQLite3 as your database, provided that electron is a framework that uses Node JS. I would use the sqlite3 lib within npm. Don't have experience with Electron, but I hope this helps.